# What is it called when you ride around on your front wheel?

Tags: tricks

I know a wheelie is when the front wheel is in the air but does it have a different name for when the back wheel is in the air?

Comment: On a BMX it's called a `nose manual`. You've tagged `road-bike` though, so I'm not sure what you'd call it on a road bike... I can't imagine doing it on anything other than a BMX or perhaps a trials bike.

Comment: @Diado Anything you can do on a trials bike [can be done on a road bike](https://youtu.be/HhabgvIIXik?t=225).

Comment: Also, I removed the "road-bike" tag as I suspect it's only there because the asker couldn't find anything better. user43208, if the question was supposed to be road-bike-specific, please edit your question to mention that in the question itself, and restore the tag. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidRicherby True, if you want it badly enough, I guess. I still can't imagine doing anything like that on anything but a BMX. I'm old fashioned, I suppose :)

Comment: Technically, a wheelie is the front wheel in the air _while pedaling_. A manual is front wheel in the air while coasting. Hence, the "nose manual" label for the back wheel in the air.

Comment: Is there a name for when *both* wheels are in the air, but one much higher than the other?  (In skateboarding it's called an "ollie" or a "nollie".)

Answer (score 28):

Rolling along balancing on the front wheel is called a "nose manual".
If it's braking to a stop while balancing on the wheel it's a "stoppie".
If it's braking to a stop suddenly with the rear wheel lifting and no front wheel rolling it's called an "endo". This last term is the short form for "end over", but only "endo" is ever uttered (thanks, erlkoenig).

Comment: Isn’t it an endo only if the rider’s center of gravity goes forward beyond the center axis of the stationary front tire while the rider has  forward momentum to spare? Otherwise it could still be a stoppie.

Comment: I'm with RoboKaren. Endo is short for end-over-end. It's a crash, or as RoboKaren eloquently puts it "forward momentum to spare"

Comment: I've always seen endo used as the trick where you balance your weight over the front wheel, even 20 years ago, from many sources. It's commonly used as a dedicated move or part of other tricks like 180° pivots on the front wheel. Even if the origin is from uncontrolled spills, endo is definitely not exclusive to crashing.

Answer (score 1):

It has many different names. Its usually called a stoppie or nose manual. Lots of people also call it a "fakie", but that term is more common in skateboarding. Some people refer to it as an "endo" but that's usually used to refer to a crash where you go over the handlebars. Other names such as nose rides, front wheelies, tip ups, and tip rides are used, but its pretty rare that someone calls them that.

Comment: Isn't "fakie" the term for riding the bicycle rolling backwards (usually on a fixed gear, but sometimes just rolling backwards down an incline)?